# Is there a way to remove gridlines from an effect_plot?

Tags: r, gridlines

For the purposes of cleaning up figures I am trying to remove the gridlines from a figure that was created using the "effect_plot" function in r, and it doesn't seem like anything I do works

I am fairly knew to using r so I may not know all of the tricks, but all of the ones I have done do not seem to work for me or I am simply putting the code in wrong. I can't seem to find a way to directly remove the gridlines in the effect_plot function.

I have used "drop_gridlines(x = TRUE, y = TRUE, minor.only = FALSE)" from https://rdrr.io/cran/jtools/man/gridlines.html

I have even tried changing the theme using theme_apa from https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/jtools/jtools.pdf

Here is the code I currently have with no attempts to remove the gridlines:

model1 <-glm(PercTomPollen~NumPolls, data=HighFlower, family="binomial")

effect_plot(model1, pred = NumPolls, intterval = TRUE, x.label = "Number of Pollinators (Floral Density= 29-894)", y.label = "Total Tomato Pollen", rescale.axis=F, int.type = "confidence", plot.points= TRUE) 
[The resulting plot from the above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1ijD.jpg)

I expect there is some way to remove the gridlines or there is simply not a way to do so in R and needs done in illustrator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `effect_plot()` creates a ggplot object, you can re-theme.

Here I set all grid lines (x, y, major, and minor) to be blank:

```
effect_plot(model1, pred = NumPolls, intterval = TRUE, x.label = "Number of Pollinators (Floral Density= 29-894)", y.label = "Total Tomato Pollen", rescale.axis=F, int.type = "confidence", plot.points= TRUE) + 
theme(panel.grid = element_blank()))
```

See [here](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/theme.html) for more components you can modify in `theme()`.

Comment: See [here](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/element.html) for `element_line()` arguments.

Comment: Thanks so much! Another question I now have is adding the axis lines. In addition to the above code I added "...+ theme( axis.line= element_line())" but nothing is appearing. I have seen another post about this but they did not accept any answer and the ones posted have not solved my problem.

Comment: That's correct, and it works for me on R 3.6.0 using ggplot 3.2.0. Try `theme(axis.line.x = element_line(), axis.line.y = element_line())`.